# Downloading an ArmA mod with steamcmd on headless Debian

Tags: debian, docker, steam, google-cloud-platform, dedicated-server

I'm running a server on google cloud headless Debian 11 (Bullseye). I've got a debian-bullseye:slim container running steamcmd. I've got the ArmA 3 dedicated server (233780) going. Normally to download a mod all I had to do was give it the line

```
./steamcmd.sh +login <uname> <passwd> +workshop_download_item 107410 2867537125 +quit
```

Now it fails here

```
WARNING: setlocale('en_US.UTF-8') failed, using locale: 'C'. International characters may not work.
Redirecting stderr to '/root/Steam/logs/stderr.txt'
[  0%] Checking for available updates...
[----] Verifying installation...
Steam Console Client (c) Valve Corporation - version 1678917456
-- type 'quit' to exit --
Loading Steam API...OK
Logging in user 'overl0rd484' to Steam Public...OK
Waiting for client config...OK
Waiting for user info...OK
Downloading item 286753715 ...ERROR! Timeout downloading item 286753715CWorkThreadPool::~CWorkThreadPool: work complete queue not empty, 2 items discarded.
CWorkThreadPool::~CWorkThreadPool: work processing queue not empty: 397 items discarded.
src/clientdll/contentupdatecontext.cpp (743) : m_uIOCurrentCacheSize == 0
src/clientdll/contentupdatecontext.cpp (743) : m_uIOCurrentCacheSize == 0
src/common/completionportmanager_posix.cpp (358) : Assertion Failed: Async I/O on closed handle 83
```

I tried downloading the ArmA 3 client for S&G, and it worked until the HDD ran out of space. I also tried downloading the mod in question (Antistasi The Mod) on a VM on my personal machine and it worked fine.

Here's the dump of that logfile

```
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1678917456)/tid(1013)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1014)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1015)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1016)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1017)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1018)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1019)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1020)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1021)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1022)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1023)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1024)
CAppInfoCacheReadFromDiskThread took 962 milliseconds to initialize
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1025)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1026)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1027)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1028)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1029)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1030)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1031)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1032)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1033)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1034)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1035)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1036)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1037)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1038)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1039)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1040)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1041)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1042)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1043)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1044)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1045)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1046)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1047)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1048)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1049)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1050)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1051)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1052)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1053)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1054)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1055)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1056)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1057)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1058)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1059)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1060)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1061)
src/clientdll/contentupdatecontext.cpp (743) : m_uIOCurrentCacheSize == 0
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamcmd)/version(1678917456)/tid(1017)
src/clientdll/contentupdatecontext.cpp (743) : m_uIOCurrentCacheSize == 0
assert_20230317002507_52.dmp[1064]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20230317002507_52.dmp
assert_20230317002507_52.dmp[1064]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = no
assert_20230317002507_52.dmp[1064]: error: libcurl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
assert_20230317002507_52.dmp[1064]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20230317002507_52.dmp'', upload no: ''libcurl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory''
src/common/completionportmanager_posix.cpp (358) : Assertion Failed: Async I/O on closed handle 83
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I never did figure out what was going on. Ended up rebuilding the server. You win some, you lose a lot.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's perfectly clear. No one answered, and I couldn't figure it out. Now that I've rebuilt the server the question is moot. I'd specifically close the question if I knew how.